# Date column values are uploading as null in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

i have a csv file, when i am trying to ingest data into kusto, datetime columns are being uploaded as blank. Does any one has idea why its happening

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your approach and any code that you have tried or any error?

Comment: I have updated my post with screenshot of the place where i am trying to upload data.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: After uploading csv i have changed my datatype to string, which resolved the issue. With datetime format its not uploading values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to ingest some csv file with datetime values in to ADX, I got null values for that column as same as yours.

[image]

This happened due to the date time format of your data. Go through the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats) to know about the Date time formats that Kusto supported.

If your column format is not any of those, then at the time of schema it will show the data type of it as string by default. We can change the type to datetime manually and if we do that it will show null values.

For sample, I have taken a sample csv data with datetime formats of `yyyy-mm-dd` and `yyyy-dd-mm`.

```
id,name,Age,DOB
1,Rakesh,22,2000-16-02
2,Laddu,23,2001-16-03
3,MS,42,1981-07-07
```

At the time of schema, it gave the string data type by default, and I have changed it to datetime manually which resulted like below.

[image]

You can see it gave null values for `yyyy-dd-mm` which is not listed in the above Documentation and given correct value for `yyyy-mm-dd`.

So, check your datetime format whether it has the formats which are not listed in the Documentation and change those according to it to avoid null values.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading csv I have changed my datatype to string, which resolved the issue. With datetime format it's not uploading values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).